# How to display a Dialog with progress spinner?

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-alertdialog

How to display a AlertDialog with a progressbar spinner?

When a button is pressed i want it to block the UI until the data is finished loading displaying a spinner and a message and title.

i know i will need to use an asyncTask for this but how do i go about displaying the dialog with progressbar spinner?

Answer (score 11):

This should be all you need

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(YourClassName.this, "", "Please wait");
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Also keep in mind that if you use ProgressDialog, you need to keep it reference for a later dismiss() and it'll crash if the orientation changes for example (because the dialog is destroyed and recreated)

So you need to update the reference, dismiss it when onPause() and recreate onResume() or use

```
...android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
```

in the AndroidManifest.xml and handle the changes on your own

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is use ProgressDialog. see the doc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html

Also, check out the dev guide for showing a dialog: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html They have a setiong about ProgressDialog.